# CSS cursor property not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css

CSS cursor property is not working in chrome and ff ? I am using the following code :

```
cursor: url(customMouse.cur), auto;
```

Please, Let me know what is the issue ?

Comment: You may find the following article interresting : http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Yes with canvas and also on body part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these,

## CSS

```
cursor: url(cursor.cur),url(cursor/cursor.cur),default;
```

Detail http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/cross-browser-custom-css-cursors/

## JQUERY (If you want)

```
// custom cursor
$(".portfolio-images img").css('cursor', function() {
     if (jQuery.browser.mozilla) {
        return 'url(image/cursor.cur), -moz-zoom-in';
    }
    else if (jQuery.browser.webkit) {
        return 'url(image/cursor.cur), -webkit-zoom-in';
    }
    else {
       return 'pointer'; 
    }
});
```

DEMO http://yeyenedesignstudio.com/logo_design